# Prevent password leakage while using sql* loader

Tags: password-protection, sql-loader

I have shell script calling Sql*loader utility which inturn uses username/password as arguments. This details cannot be stored on server in any form due to security related policies. i got 2 approaches to handle this situation, 
1. create hidden parameter file with login details and limit the access to owner. 
again the implication is i cannot store login data in any format on server
2. Create the user as OS authenticated and straight away login into sql without any userid/password
I am not able to figure out risks involved in 2nd approach which u experienced folks could have come across. 
let me know if there is any other approach to handle password leakage issue

Answer (score -1):

If you use windows, you can use DOS variables to store the password.
Make two variables, called sqlldr_user and sqlldr_password (or call them sq_jfkd and sq_tral to not make it too obvious what it is). You can do this under System Properties (windows+break)->advanced->environment variables.

In your sqlldr batch file, use %sqlldr_user%/%sqlldr_pass@connectstring, control=my_control